# iOS: is prepareForSegue callback for the other direction (i.e. back button pressed)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm wondering if there's a callback, similar to `prepareForSegue`, which gets called when returning to a parent UIViewController, when the user preses the [back] button.

I'd also like to get the information, from which child view controller the user came from, meaning, in which view controller the user pressed the back button.

Answer (score 2):

Use delegate methods if you want to get data back from a pushed (or modal) VC.  If you need an example, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483100/iphone-navigation-back-button/9483288#9483288)